# Why is XGBoost deterministic?

Tags: python, boosting

I ran [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on the same dataset multiple times, and set its random seed parameter to different values, and I get the exact same feature importances each time. So it seems like it's deterministic, which doesn't make much sense to me since it uses decision trees. Was wondering if anyone has any insight on this.

Comment: You would expect an algorithm to give different results each time? Are the predictions *exactly* the same? It’s good that the *properties* of the model are reproducible, isn’t it?

Comment: Decision trees are mostly deterministic, barring ties or random subsampling (rows or columns).  Did you set any hyperparameters to subsample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment from @BenReiniger, XGBoost *can* be deterministic, but it probably shouldn't be run that way.

According to the [XGBoost parameter settings](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html), the default for `subsample`, the "subsample ratio of the training instances," is 1. With that setting, *all* cases in the training set will be used at each iteration--deterministic. In contrast, the default for the corresponding `bag.fraction` in the R [`gbm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gbm) is 0.5, with only half of the training cases used at each iteration--random.

Also for XGBoost, the defaults for the subsampling of features, `colsample_bytree`, `colsample_bylevel`, and `colsample_bynode` are all equal to 1, for no subsampling of features.

So with the default XGBoost parameter settings, there is no subsampling either of cases or features. You thus should get deterministic results. With those settings, however, you lose many of the protections against overfitting and thus lose the generally better application to new instances that subsampling both cases and features in XGBoost provides.

I can't rule out your having a peculiar data set as the answer from @EngrStudent suggests, but change your settings for subsampling of cases or features and see what happens.

Comment: I know this is dataset dependent, but what are sensible values for these parameters to use as a default?

Comment: @AnIgnorantWanderer my sense is that `subsample` of 0.5 is common; you'll note that's the example used in documentation for `XGBoost` parameter settings, and the default for the corresponding setting in `gbm`. I don't have much experience with feature subsampling. As feature subsampling underlies random forest, you might try the rule of thumb of sampling $\sqrt p$ out of $p$ features (Section 8.2.2 of [ISLR](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/)) for `bytree`.  Don't know how to think about the `bylevel` or `bynode` settings; be careful, those 3 settings are cumulative.

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT deterministic.

You may have used a data set that is well behaved on replication, but it should be randomly sampling in rows and columns per tree.  This speeds up training and improves generalization.

Unless one intentionally sets the tool to do the exhaustive search every time, it should not ever be deterministic.

Check the last digit of the importances for the same variable between different runs.